# Как сделать анимацию FAB transforming into a single sheet of materia

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-animation

Как сделать такую анимацию или каким способом?

[image: FAB transforming into a single sheet of materia]

Comment: возможно [эта библиотека](https://github.com/gowong/material-sheet-fab) окажется полезной